# How can I put the output of spctl command into a notification dialog using Automator?

Tags: terminal, automator, digital-signature

I would like to output the result of `spctl --assess --verbose path/to/app.app` in a notification dialog using Automator. However, it doesn't work. I assume it's because the command returns a multi-line output, such as

`/Applications/Test.app: accepted`

`source=Notarized Developer ID`

I tried passing the output of the shell script to a Set Value of Variable action and then putting the variable in a Display Notification action. I tried using a Ask for Confirmation action instead. Since it didn't work, I tried passing the output of the command to a New TextEdit Document action, but the new document ended up blank. I tried appending `| tr '\n' ' '`  to replace the new line character with a space but that didn't work. I would appreciate any help. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: What else are you doing that requires AppleScript? There's a nifty new dialog message box tool with input/output capabilities from IBM that is used quite a bit in scripting by enterprise admins. Don't knock it because it is IBM.  IBM has embraced Mac's and iOS/iPadOS development and they have over 500K employees with Macs.  https://github.com/IBM/mac-ibm-notifications/wiki/Usage

Comment: If you click the **[Results]** _button_ on the **Run Shell Script** _action_ I think you'll see there is nothing in its _window_  as `spctl` for some reason is not outputting anything.